# Авторизация через соц. сети на сайтах

Tags: android, авторизация

В моем приложении-клиенте для онлайн-игры есть вход через все соц. сети.
Использую скрытый `WebView` в котором выполняю авторизацию.

Проблема в том, что на всех этих соц. сетях есть вход через другие соц. сети. Эти хитросплетения соц. сетей мне обернулись злом - очень много пользователей жалуются что не могут войти в игру, так как у меня реализован лишь вход по форме.

Подскажите, посоветуйте что делать, возможно ли вообще сделать вход через соц. сети на соц. сети, чтобы не потерять свой дизайн?

Скрытый `WebView` и всю логику не очень хочется менять на вход через `WebView`